# Func returning before second healthkit query complete

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit, hkhealthstore

I am trying to get both stepsQuantityType and kjActiveQuantityType for a given date from HealthKit.

I can get both queries to work if fun separately but when trying to run them together in the same function the ruction returns before the second query is complete giving an index out of range error as  index 1 of the array has not been filled.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

i call the func using

```
getTodaysStepsAndKJ { arrayData in
            self.stepsHolder = arrayData[0]
            self.kjHolder = arrayData[1] * 4.184
            DispatchQueue.main.async {self.stepsLabel.text = arrayData[0].description;
                                      self.kjLabel.text = (arrayData[1] * 4.184).description}
            self.saveDataToCloud()
        }
```

and the func is

```
func getTodaysStepsAndKJ(completion: @escaping (Array<Double>) -> Void) {
      let stepsQuantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount)!
      let kjActiveQuantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .activeEnergyBurned)!
      var resultArray = Array<Double>();
      let now = Date()
      let startOfDay = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: now)
      let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startOfDay, end: now, options: .strictStartDate)

      let query = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: stepsQuantityType, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: .cumulativeSum) { _, result, _ in
          guard let result = result, let sum = result.sumQuantity() else {
            resultArray.insert(0.0, at: 0)
            completion(resultArray)
              return
          }
        resultArray.insert(sum.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count()), at: 0)
          completion(resultArray)

      }
        let query2 = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: kjActiveQuantityType, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: .cumulativeSum) { _, result, _ in
            guard let result = result, let sum = result.sumQuantity() else {
                resultArray.insert(0.0, at: 1)
                completion(resultArray)
                return
            }
            resultArray.insert(sum.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.kilocalorie()), at: 1)
            completion(resultArray)
        }
    healthStore.execute(query)
    healthStore.execute(query2)
  }
```

When split and run as two functions they both work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you take query2 inside query one ... then it can work .. roughly something like following ...not tested code

```
func getTodaysStepsAndKJ(completion: @escaping (Array<Double>) -> Void) {
      let stepsQuantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount)!
      let kjActiveQuantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .activeEnergyBurned)!
      var resultArray = Array<Double>();
      let now = Date()
      let startOfDay = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: now)
      let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startOfDay, end: now, options: .strictStartDate)

      let query = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: stepsQuantityType, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: .cumulativeSum) { _, result, _ in
          guard let result = result, let sum = result.sumQuantity() else {
            resultArray.insert(0.0, at: 0)
            completion(resultArray)
              return
          }
        resultArray.insert(sum.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count()), at: 0)
           let query2 = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: kjActiveQuantityType, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: .cumulativeSum) { _, result, _ in
            guard let result = result, let sum = result.sumQuantity() else {
                resultArray.insert(0.0, at: 1)
                completion(resultArray)
                return
            }
            resultArray.insert(sum.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.kilocalorie()), at: 1)
            completion(resultArray)
        }
      healthStore.execute(query2)
      }

    healthStore.execute(query)

  }
```

Comment: I made a small edit, moving the "healthStore.execute(query2)" into the first query but otherwise your answer works a treat! Thanks